# Add Score in maze game written in java

Tags: java, swing, grid, jpanel, paint

I am going to make a maze game in java. I have done almost but i have facing problem to add score. I have add the time spend to end the game, but it doesn;t terminate. here is my code. Please help me to print the total time.....

```
package Maze;   
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
 {
     private Timer timer;
     private Map m;
     private Player p;
     private boolean win=false;
     long startTime=0;
     long message=0;

     public Board()
     {
         startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
         m= new Map();
         p= new Player();
         addKeyListener(new Al());
         setFocusable(true);
         timer=new Timer(25, this);
         timer.start();
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         if(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()).equals("f"))
         {               
             win=true;
             message=(startTime+10000)-System.currentTimeMillis();
         }

        repaint(); 
     }
     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
        super.paint(g);
        if(!win&&(System.currentTimeMillis()<=(startTime+10000)))
        {
         for(int y=0;y<14;y++)
         {
             for(int x=0;x<14;x++)
             {
                 if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("f"))
                     g.drawImage(m.getFinish(), x*32, y*32, null);
                 if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("w"))
                        g.drawImage(m.getWall(), x*32, y*32, null);
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("g"))
                        g.drawImage(m.getGrass(), x*32, y*32, null);

             }
         }
         g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(), p.getTileX()*32, p.getTileY()*32,null);
        }

            else if(win)
             {
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long time=end-startTime;
                //String str=Long.toString(time);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Score:"+time);
                //System.exit(0);
                //g.drawImage(m.getWinn(), 32, 32, null);
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Winner");
             }
        else
        {
            g.drawImage(m.getLose(), 32, 32, null);
        }

     }
     public class Al extends KeyAdapter{

         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        /*   long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
             totalTime=(startTime1-startTime)/1000;
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,totalTime); */   
             int keycode= e.getKeyCode();

             if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_UP )
             {
                 if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()-1).equals("w"))
                 {
                     p.move( 0, -1);
                 }
             }

             if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN )
             {
                 if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()+1).equals("w"))
                 {
                     p.move( 0, 1);
                 }
             }
             if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT )
             {
                 if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX()-1,p.getTileY()).equals("w"))
                 {
                     p.move( -1, 0);
                 }
             }
             if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )
             {
                 if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX()+1,p.getTileY()).equals("w"))
                 {
                     p.move( 1, 0  );    
                 }

             }

         }

     }
 }
```

and here is my confusion point

```
else if(win)
{
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time=end-startTime;
    // String str=Long.toString(time);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Score:"+time);
    // System.exit(0);
    // g.drawImage(m.getWinn(), 32, 32, null);
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Winner");
}
```

Comment: I don't think paint is the place y want or be trying to make these decisions. Better to make use if a generic state flag and evaluate/set it else where. May be use something like a javax.swing.Timer to trigger the time out (or even to tick out the timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the game to finish if:

- The player wins: `win == true`, or
- The time's over: `System.currentTimeMillis() <= (startTime+10000)`

If that's the case, your `if` condition.-

```
if (!win && (System.currentTimeMillis() <= (startTime + 10000)))
```

would be ok, but your else branch.-

```
else if(win)
```

would be just:

```
else
```

instead. In other words: as long as the player haven't won and there's time left, the game go on. Otherwise (regardless the player did win or not), show score.